# How to fix this error[2045] or this [1054] I always get this message in terminal when i try to migrate table

Tags: php, laravel, migration, artisan-migrate

when I type `php artisan migrate` in terminal

I get this error number `[2054]` and sometimes `[1054]` !

I tried to change everything like `host`, `username` and `password` in `.env` file

`database.php` and `config.php` file,  but it didn't work well

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = lsapp and table_name = migrations)
>
> at /Users/Ali/education/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
>       660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
>       661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
>       662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
>       663|         catch (Exception $e) {
>   664|             throw new QueryException(
>       665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
>       666|             );
>       667|         }
>       668|

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel + Vagrant = Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311553/laravel-vagrant-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I got the solution by downloading MySQL Workbench then create a new database in this app , and it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

The error says you do not have permission to do queries. You need to access with the password and/or the database must have a password.

Verify the access codes (user, password) or try to access by a web manager, like phpmyadmin, pgadmin, etc ...

Comment: Thanks Patrick , I got the solution by download MySQLWorkbench then create  database via this application .